# How to make fig.width and out.width consistent with knitr?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, tikz

I have recently discovered knitr and I mainly use it to produce plots with `dev=tikz` to get a Latex typesetting easily. However I don't understand how to set chunk options `fig.width` and `out.width` with consistency.

I mean, I know that the first one is an R option while the second one is the latex option coming with `\includegraphics` but it seems like if `fig.width` is too large compared to `out.width` then the lines are very thin because latex shrink the picture. In the other hand if it's too small then latex streches it and everything is too big.

Basically I'd like too have a setting in wich I only choose the `out.width`and then the thickness of the lines and texts is consistent with the text size of the document.

I include a MWE illustrating my problem. Also I have set `fig.height` in the first example otherwise the picture was then bigger than the page, I don't really understand this as well.

Any help is warmly welcome !

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
  library(knitr)
  options(formatR.arrow=TRUE,width=50)
  opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/graphics-', 
                 cache.path='cache/graphics-', 
                 fig.align='center', 
                 dev='tikz')
@

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    <<fig_1,fig.width=2,  fig.height = 3,out.width = '\\textwidth',echo=FALSE>>=
    x = seq(1,3,l=100)
    plot(x,cos(x), type ="l", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
    @
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
<<fig_2,fig.width=10,  out.width = '\\textwidth',echo=FALSE>>=
    x = seq(1,3,l=100)
    plot(x,cos(x), type ="l", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
    @
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the figure height has a default value (I guess around 5 inches, didn't check), and since you're setting a smaller width, when latex resizes the graphic to the full page width the height blows up in proportion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically NO resizing should be made after the `tikzpicture` has been created, because it will lose consistency with text style. As a matter of fact, when chunk option `cache=FALSE` is set, then `out.width` has no effect because no pdf output is created. Hence one has to specify exact measures in inches for `fig.width`and `fig.height` for each chunk.

After some research both on stackoverflow and in Knitr websites, I have found a trick to have almost the same *user experience*, ie that I don't want to care about real sizes but only think relatively to `\textwidth` and other Latex variables:

- in the setup chunk, define R variables with explicit name (such as `paperwidth`, `textwidth` corresponding to the Latex one in inches, eg an A4 paper is (w,h) = (8.3, 11.7).
- in each chunk with a plot, you can then use `fig.width = 0.5*paperwidth`for example

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
  library(knitr)
  options(formatR.arrow=TRUE,width=50)
  opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/graphics-', 
                 cache.path='cache/graphics-', 
                 fig.align='center',
                 dev='tikz',
                 external=TRUE,
                 echo=FALSE
                )
  a4width<- 8.3
  a4height<- 11.7
@

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
<<fig_1, fig.width = 0.4*a4width, fig.height = 0.2*a4height>>=
    x = seq(1,3,l=100)
    plot(x,cos(x), type ="l", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
@

<<fig_2, fig.width = 0.2*a4width, fig.height = 0.5*a4height>>=
    x = seq(1,3,l=100)
    plot(x,cos(x), type ="l", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
@

\caption{Test figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't have `\begin{figure}` since knitr will include them for you. Also, I find it best when LaTeX does not resize the figures at all, i.e. they're already of the right size. Here's an example, where I set up the text width to 6 inches, and the figure width to the same value.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
  library(knitr)
  options(formatR.arrow=TRUE,width=50)
  opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/graphics-', 
                 cache.path='cache/graphics-', 
                 fig.align='center', 
                 dev='tikz')
@

\usepackage[text={6in,9in},centering]{geometry}
\begin{document}

    <<fig_1, fig.width=6, echo=FALSE>>=
    x = seq(1,3,l=100)
    plot(x,cos(x), type ="l", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
@

<<fig_2, fig.width=6, out.width = '\\textwidth',echo=FALSE>>=
    x = seq(1,3,l=100)
    plot(x,cos(x), type ="l", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It wasn't was I was expected exactly but made me look deeper into knitr options. Finally you were right about the fact that `out.width` should NOT be used with tikz device. I have several comments to my question so I add its as an answer.

Comment: and figure environment is set only if chunk option `fig.cap` is set